# SQLAlchemy aggregated query through non-standard many-to-many table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following schema:

`Organization` has a list of `Customer`s and every `Customer` has a list of `Certification`s.  `Customer`s are associated with `Certification`s through a model called `OrganizationCustomerMetadata`.  `OrganizationCustomerMetadata` has a string `key`, a string `value`, and an integer `customer_id`.  It's just a per-customer key-value store with other stuff in there besides certification mappings.  When the `key` is "certification", the `value` is a certification id.  (It was like that when I got here.)

I want to count the number of times each `Certification` has been applied to a `Customer` across an entire `Organization`.

I wrote the method below to do this:

```
def get_user_counts(self, org_id):
    if not org_id:
        return {}
    certs_sql = text(
        '''
        select certifications.id, count(*) as user_count from certifications
        join organization_customer_metadata on value::int = certifications.id and
        key = 'certification'
        join customers on organization_customer_metadata.customer_id = customers.id
        where customers.organization_id = {org_id} and certifications.state = 'ACTIVE'
        group by certifications.id;
        '''.format(org_id=int(org_id)))
    certs_query = db.engine.execute(certs_sql)
    return {row[0]: row[1] for row in certs_query}
```

This is part of a larger API call that queries and filters all of the `Certification`s used by an `Organization`.  After calculating the certification counts I then tack them on to each of the `Certification`s to be returned like so:

```
    # ...some code here that queries for a bunch of certifications...

    user_counts = self.controller.get_user_counts(organization_id)
    for cert in certifications:
        cert.user_count = user_counts.get(cert.id, 0)
```

I'd like to rewrite all of this with proper sqlalchemy functions.  And I think I should also make `user_counts` an aggregated attribute on the `Certification` model, right?  I'm new to sqlalchemy and am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to do this.  Any suggestions?